# Can I use LSTM for Text Classification into Categories?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, lstm

I want to train an LSTM Network, since it accepts Sequences as Input, and I plan to instead of using the bag-of-words representation, I want to replace each word with it's semantic vector, provided by word2vec or GloVe for example.

I'm trying to use that on Keras, and as output, I only want K outputs, representing the K categories that the text should belong.

Here is what I'm trying to do, but I can't figure out how can I finish it:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('/home/brunoalano/data.csv', header=None, names=["text", "category"])
word_vector_model = Word2Vec()
index_dict = { w:i for i,w in enumerate(word_vector_model.model.model.index2word) }

model = Sequential()
model.add(
  Embedding(
    output_dim=word_vector_model.model.dimension,
    input_dim=n_symbols,
    mask_zero=True,
    weights=[embedding_weights],
    input_length=input_length
  )
)
model.add(LSTM(word_vector_model.model.dimension))
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) # try 0.3
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

So, it's possible to use this model for my purpose?

Comment: Hello Brunno, look here: http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/ at first picture - you probably would like to implement 3rd example, aren't you? Of course you can do this in keras. You should set return_sequence to False at the end of your LSTM, then you can connect output to e.g. Dense, or use it just as output of neural network.

Comment: This is one of the examples provided in the Keras Documentation article [Getting started with the Keras Sequential model](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) under the header "Sequence classification with LSTM". After you copy-paste the code, use a categorical loss function.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would add a display of the model. After the `model.compile(...)` add:

```
model.summary()
```

This will give you a good picture of the data flow through the layers.

Second, I would move the `Dropout(...)` layer right after the `Embedding` layer. If you are going to randomly drop samples then do it as early as possible to avoid doing unnecessary training.

Then, your `Dense(...)` layer should use `activation='softmax'`

Lastly, your `model.compile` should specify `loss='categorical_crossentropy'` since you want classification to 14 categories (not two which is binary classification). I would also suggest you add a:
    `metrics=['accuracy']` to the `model.compile`.